# Как вывести категории 3-го уровня в меню навигации в php?

Tags: php, mysql

Как мне сделать вывод категории третьего уровня из этой модели:

```
/** @var integer $nSubSlice - максимально допустимое видимое кол-во подкатегорий */
$nSubSlice = 10;
$aData = $this->model->catsList($sType, $mDevice, $nParentID, $ICON_BIG);
if (!empty($aData)) {
    $aData = $this->db->transformRowsToTree($aData, 'id', 'pid', 'sub');
    foreach ($aData as $k => $v) {
        $v['l'] = $sListingUrl . $v['k'] . '/';
        $v['i'] = $oIcon->url($v['id'], $v['i'], $ICON_BIG);
        foreach ($v['sub'] as $kk => $vv) {
            $v['sub'][$kk]['l'] = $sListingUrl . $vv['k'] . '/';
        }
        $v['subn'] = sizeof($v['sub']); # всего подкатегорий
        $v['sub'] = array_slice($v['sub'], 0, $nSubSlice); # оставляем не более {$nSubSlice}
        $v['subv'] = sizeof($v['sub']); # кол-во отображаемых подкатегорий
        $aData[$k] = $v;
    }
}
$aData = array('cats' => $aData);
```

вывод меню навигации:

```
<?php $i = 0; foreach($cats as $k=>$v): ?>
<li class="has-children">
    <i class="cat-icon icon-furniture"></i>
    <a href="#"><?= $v['t'] ?></a> //здесь выводится название рубрики без родителя
    <ul class="cd-secondary-nav is-hidden">
        <? if($v['subn']): ?>
        <? $j = 0; foreach($v['sub'] as $vv) { ?>
        <li class="has-children">
            <a href="<?= $vv['l'] ?>"><?= $vv['t'] ?></a> //здесь выводятся названия категорий 2го уровня
            <ul class="is-hidden">
               //здесь должен быть цыкл категории 3го уровня
              <li><a href="ссылка на категорию 3го уровня">Название категории третего уровня</a></li>
              //конец цыкла категорий 3го уровня
            </ul>
        </li>
        <? if($j++ < $v['subv']); } ?>
        <? endif; ?>
    </ul>
</li>
<? if($i++%2) { ?><? } endforeach; ?>
```

покажите пожалуйста правильный вывод

в одном из [форумах](https://www.nulled.cc/threads/287362/page-7) одна девушка задавала этот вопрос, ей ответили, но я и она не поняли

**ОТВЕТ С ФОРУМА:**

```
Собственно у вас сейчас, после выборки из БД по фильтру C.numlevel < 3 и обработки, имеется вот такой массив, в котором естественного нужного вам нет.
Код:
Array
(
    [cats] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [pid] => 1
                    [i] => //xxxxxxxx/files/images/cats/2o1f5e.png
                    [t] => Недвижимость
                    [k] => nedvizhimost
                    [items] => 15
                    [subs] => 1
                    [lvl] => 1
                    [sub] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1305
                                    [pid] => 2
                                    [i] =>
                                    [t] => Аренда недвижимости
                                    [k] => nedvizhimost/arenda-nedvizhimosti
                                    [items] => 2
                                    [subs] => 1
                                    [lvl] => 2
                                    [sub] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [l] => http://xxxxxxxx/moskva/search/nedvizhimost/arenda-nedvizhimosti/
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1306
                                    [pid] => 2
                                    [i] =>
                                    [t] => Продажа недвижимости
                                    [k] => nedvizhimost/prodazha-nedvizhimosti
                                    [items] => 13
                                    [subs] => 1
                                    [lvl] => 2
                                    [sub] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [l] => http://xxxxxxxx/moskva/search/nedvizhimost/prodazha-nedvizhimosti/
                                )
Отфильтруйте запрос например так C.numlevel < 4 это вам даст
Код:
Array
(
    [cats] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [pid] => 1
                    [i] => //xxxxxxxx/files/images/cats/2o1f5e.png
                    [t] => Недвижимость
                    [k] => nedvizhimost
                    [items] => 15
                    [subs] => 1
                    [lvl] => 1
                    [sub] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1305
                                    [pid] => 2
                                    [i] =>
                                    [t] => Аренда недвижимости
                                    [k] => nedvizhimost/arenda-nedvizhimosti
                                    [items] => 2
                                    [subs] => 1
                                    [lvl] => 2
                                    [sub] => Array
                                        (
                                            [15] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 15
                                                    [pid] => 1305
                                                    [i] =>
                                                    [t] => Аренда квартир
                                                    [k] => nedvizhimost/arenda-nedvizhimosti/arenda-kvartir
                                                    [items] => 2
                                                    [subs] => 1
                                                    [lvl] => 3
                                                    [sub] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [9] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 9
                                                    [pid] => 1305
                                                    [i] =>
                                                    [t] => Аренда комнат
                                                    [k] => nedvizhimost/arenda-nedvizhimosti/arenda-komnat
                                                    [items] => 0
                                                    [subs] => 1
                                                    [lvl] => 3
                                                    [sub] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )
Получив данные обрабатываете и выводите по задаче. В любом случае, если ваших знаний не хватает, ищите программиста под проект.
```

Comment: думаю не многим охота регатся на форуме что бы посмотреть изображения и ответ который вам там дали, дополните вопрос что ли, а ссылка как источник

Comment: Обновил вопрос !